# Get array in mapping from another contract

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

I have contract Users, that contains users list and nftInstance:

```
contract Users {
    struct UserData{
        User user;
        bool exists;
    }

    mapping (address => UserData) public users;
    NFT public nftInstance;

    constructor() {
        nftInstance = new NFT();
    }

    event UserConnect(User user);

    function connectUser() public  {
        address userAddress = msg.sender;

        if(users[userAddress].exists) emit UserConnect(users[userAddress].user);
        else {
            User user = new User(userAddress, nftInstance);
            users[userAddress].user = user;
            users[userAddress].exists = true;
            emit UserConnect(user);
        }
    }

    function getUser(address _userAddress) public view returns (User){
        return users[_userAddress].user;
    }
}
```

And i have `User` contract. In constructor i get nftInstance to be able to create NFT in `User` . And store NFTs in one storage. This is my `User contract`:

```
contract User {
    address public userAddress;
    NFT private nftInstance;

    constructor (address _userAddress, NFT _nftInstance) {
        userAddress = _userAddress;
        nftInstance = _nftInstance;
    }

    event Collect(string tokenURI);

    function collect() public{
        uint256 tokenId = nftInstance.createNFT(userAddress);
        emit Collect(nftInstance.tokenURI(tokenId));
    }

    function getMyNFTs() public {
        mapping(address => uint256) storage tokenIdsCount = nftInstance.userAddressToTokenId; // 1 VARIANT
        uint256[] memory tokenIds = nftInstance.userAddressToTokenId[userAddress]; // 2 VARIANT
    }
}
```

In NFT contract i have such mapping: `mapping(address => uint256[]) public userAddressToTokenId;`
And i try to get this mapping data in `User`. But this is wrong

> 1 - TypeError: Type function (address,uint256) view external returns (uint256) is not implicitly convertible to expected type mapping(address => uint256).
>
> 2 - ypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (address,uint256) view external returns (uint256))

So, how to get `tokenIds` array from mapping of `NFT` contract instance?

Comment: I'm amazed that you dared to post this code here ;D

Comment: It's okay, just some protest;)

Comment: @Kaneda so, how to interact with mapping from another contract?

Comment: Can you include NFT how `tokenIds` are defined in the `NFT` contract? In any case a contract can't access the storage area of another contract directly the only way to do so is for the second contract to have public getter functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a getter in the `NFT` contract to get mapping

```
function getTokenIdsFromAddress(address _userAddress) public view 
 returns(uint256[] memory) {
    return userAddressToTokenId[_userAddress];
}
```